# React Component inside .map() is throwing an error: TypeError: notes.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

am trying to show **Noteitem** component which is returned inside a map function.

```js
        {notes.map((note) => {
          return (
            <Noteitem key={note._id} updateNote={updateNote} showAlert={props.showAlert} note={note} />
          );
        })}
```

Comment: `notes` is not an array that means, so you can do as `notes?.map`

Answer (score 0):

`notes` should be an array for `map` function to work. You can check it in following way if `notes` is not `null` and is an array using `notes.length` and apply `map` function

```
{notes && notes.length && notes.map((note) => {
          return (
            <Noteitem key={note._id} updateNote={updateNote} showAlert={props.showAlert} note={note} />
          );
        })}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put if/else statement inside JSX to check the variable whether is exist or not

```
return (
   <>
      {
        notes.length
           ? 'fallback'
           : notes.map(note => <Noteitem key={note._id} updateNote={updateNote} showAlert={props.showAlert} note={note} />)
      }
   </>
)
```

IIFE

```
{(() => {
   if ("check note") {
      // fallback
   }
   return notes.map((note: NoteProps) => (
      <Noteitem key={note._id} updateNote={updateNote} showAlert={props.showAlert} note={note} />
   ));
})()}
```